# scala: How to know the program have unhandled exceptions before running?

Tags: scala

this is a test program:

```
object Test {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        // there is an unhandled exception in here, I expect program can remind me, and I can handled it before running.
        myException()  
    }

    def myException: Unit ={
        throw new Exception
    }
}
```

In Java, when I called a method with unhandling exception, the program will occur error, and tell you `add throws declaration` or `surround with try/catch`.

How to know the program have unhandled exceptions before running in **Scala**?

Answer (score 9):

Scala has a somewhat different philosophy with regards to `Exception`s.

The rule of thumb is to not use them unless for something truly exceptional and, thus "let it fail". The reason invoked behind this rule is that, in FP terms, exceptions break referential transparency.

The good practice is to use `Either` or `Option` to handle/wrap "errors" rather than throwing exceptions. (the link provided by @Tawkir seems a good read)

Unfortunately this does not help when interfacing with Java code which often uses Exceptions for program control flow, and the compiler will not help you there. A practical way around this is to wrap Exception throwing code with a `Try` and then call `recover` or `recoverWith` to handle these exceptions and, say, wrap them in another structure.

Please note that you can mark a scala method with an `@throws` annotation to specify the Exception(s) that this method throws, but this should really be used when writing scala code meant to be used by a Java caller expecting an Exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

There's no distinction between checked and unchecked exceptions in the JVM. This is only enforced in the Java compiler, based on whether the class extends RuntimeException or not. Scala compiler doesn't check it, so, there is no way to know, does program have unhandled unchecked exceptions, or not.